# SpringBoot 1.5.2:Required request body is missing when i make PUT RequestMethod

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I want to test REST application, I try to write a test code segment like below:

Controller Code:

```
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/Test")
public class test {

    @RequestMapping(value="test1/{modelId}",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void test1(@PathVariable(value="modelId") String modelId,     @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> values){
        String name = values.getFirst("name");
        String description = values.getFirst("description");
        System.out.println(modelId);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(description);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="test2",consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void test2( @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> values){
        String name = values.getFirst("name");
        String description = values.getFirst("description");
          System.out.println(name);
          System.out.println(description);
    }
}
```

and below is Ajax call function:

```
function start() {
    var data1 = "test";
    var data2 = "test model";

    var jdata = {name:data1,description:data2};
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        async: false,
        url: "/Test/test2",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        data: jdata,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
}
```

I can get the right result when i call `http://localhost:8080/Test/test1/123`.
but when i try to call `http://localhost:8080/Test/test2`,the console display warning:

```
WARN  o.s.w.s.m.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message:
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
Required request body is missing:
public void com.wisto.util.test.test2(org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
```

and the browser get 400 error.

I think I must miss something about config of SpringBoot. How can I solve it?

For More clearer,I put a True Code From Activiti
    package org.activiti.rest.editor.model;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.activiti.editor.constants.ModelDataJsonConstants;
import org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException;
import org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService;
import org.activiti.engine.repository.Model;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

/**
 * @author Tijs Rademakers
*/
@RestController
public class ModelSaveRestResource implements ModelDataJsonConstants {

  protected static final Logger LOGGER =    LoggerFactory.getLogger(ModelSaveRestResource.class);

  @Autowired
  private RepositoryService repositoryService;

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @RequestMapping(value="/model/{modelId}/save", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
  public void saveModel(@PathVariable String modelId, @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> values) {
    try {

      Model model = repositoryService.getModel(modelId);

      ObjectNode modelJson = (ObjectNode)   objectMapper.readTree(model.getMetaInfo());

      modelJson.put(MODEL_NAME, values.getFirst("name"));
      modelJson.put(MODEL_DESCRIPTION, values.getFirst("description"));
      model.setMetaInfo(modelJson.toString());
      model.setName(values.getFirst("name"));

      repositoryService.saveModel(model);

      repositoryService.addModelEditorSource(model.getId(), values.getFirst("json_xml").getBytes("utf-8"));

      InputStream svgStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(values.getFirst("svg_xml").getBytes("utf-8"));
      TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgStream);

      PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();
      // Setup output
      ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outStream);

      // Do the transformation
      transcoder.transcode(input, output);
      final byte[] result = outStream.toByteArray();
      repositoryService.addModelEditorSourceExtra(model.getId(), result);
      outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Error saving model", e);
      throw new ActivitiException("Error saving model", e);
    }
  }
}
```

The Code above works well with Spring.But with SpringBoot.So I am confused!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your data object is converted to a string as the payload.
Try:
`data:JSON.stringify(jdata)`

Also content type should be:

`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: I just give a simple data in this test example.Actually,I want to PUT a more complicated data to my server.For example,I also want to put a json_xml and svg_xml from a svg file.So i use contextType application/x-www-form-urlencoded.As I mentioned,the "test1" can get the right result.The problem is when i use PUT and application/x-www-form-urlencoded,I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dataType parameter in ajax. Your code is specifying data type is **JSON** but controller is get as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

You can make it `dataType: 'text'`

Or if you use JSON for the request Then change the following

1. in controller `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`
2. in ajax parameter `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: But if I want to put more complicated data to my server?For example name:XX,description:XX,json_xml:{xxxxxx}

Comment: What kind of data will be in json_xml? Otherwise it look like you can use json

Comment: And what about the existing question? Was that approach fixed your problem? You have changed your question's mapping parameters as well

Comment: Actually,I want to save an activiti digram xml to my server.The data include the model's name,description,json_xml,and svg_xml

Comment: You have to make clear that how you are trying to send xml to controller and how you need to be.

Comment: something like this:
name:xxx
description:xxx
json_xml:json_xml:{"resourceId":"15001","properties":{"process_id":"process","name":"","documentation":"","process_author":""}

Comment: So it looks like `json_xml` can be send as `json` to the controller. Isn't it?